# npm premature close on jenkins build

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, deployment, node-gyp

I'm setting up a Jenkins build for our internal NodeJS Express project.

The project uses some native libraries (written in C). After trial & error setting up Python, MSBuild Tools (with `windows-build-tools` and without), I didn't managed to get the build working.

Jenkins script:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Download source') {
        steps {
            checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM', 
                branches: [[name: '*/branch-name']], 
                userRemoteConfigs: 
                [
                    [
                        credentialsId: 'cred-id', 
                        url: 'gitURL'
                    ]
                ]
            ])
        }
    }

    stage('Npm install') {
      steps {
        bat "npm install"
      }
    }
  }     
}
```

I've tried with the NodeJS plugin, same issue. Granted permissions to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins` folder and every sub-directory, reinstalled everything (packages, Node with different versions, even my Windows OS), but the output is always:

```
step: npm install
npm ERR! premature close

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-04T16_69_111Z-debug.log
```

**The weird thing** is that when I run `npm install` from the `%JENKINS_HOME%workspace/ProjectName` folder, it builds and installs everything without any warnings or errors and runs smoothly.

Sorry for the long text, I've done a 3 week research on this topic, saw many articles and posts, but this problem has been for a longer period and we can't manage to build any of our Node projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after 2 more weeks of miserable attempts to make this work, the only solution that works is:

`yarn install`

Instead of:

`npm install`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this issue is just

`yarn install` instead of `npm install`

And then:
`yarn add --save github:user/repo`

Comment: This has already been mentioned in some of the other answers. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.